# One shot learning for a regression task

Tags: deep-learning, regression

I know one shot learning can be used for classification as in the Siamese-network, but can we use one shot learning for a regression task?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. If you use an LSTM layer, you can define the time-steps parameter in the input i.e. you may define the k previous time-steps to learn how to predict the next k time-steps values.